# Capturar parametro cuando esta en estado checked y le doy click al boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este `ajax`

```
$(function() {
    //function ajax
    $('#example-table .processPreset').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elemento = $(this);
        var idArt = elemento.parent().parent().find('#id_articulo').text();
        console.log(idArt);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/processPreset',
            method: 'post',
            data: { idArticulo: idArt },
            success: function(res) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es capturar el numero de articulo cuando el checkbox esta seleccionado y le doy al boton guardar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el `jade`

```
div(class="container aDetallado")
    div(class="row center span10")
      table(id='example-table' class='table table-striped table-hover table-condensed analisisD')
        thead
          tr
            th='Articulo'
            th='Descripción'
            th='Um'
            th='Ov'
            th='#Ubic'
            th='Teorico'
            th(class='vi1')='Conteo1'
            th(class='vi2')='Conteo2'
            th(class='vi3')='Conteo3'
            th='Dif'
            th='Dif $'
            th(class='vi3')='Asignar conteo'
            th='Seleccionar'
              input(type="checkbox" id='selectall')

          tbody
          if ListArticulos != undefined
            each Articulos in ListArticulos
              tr
                td(id='id_articulo' class='iarticulo')= Articulos.SI_Articulo
                td= Articulos.SI_Descripcion
                td= Articulos.SI_UM
                td= Articulos.SI_OV
                td
                  button(type='button' id='btn-analisisInterno' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal')= Articulos.SI_Ubicacion
                td= Articulos.SI_Existencia
                td(class='vi1')= Articulos.SI_Cantidad
                td(class='vi2')
                td(class='vi3')
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif_Dinero
                td(class='vi3')
                  select(class='form-control widthSelect' name='mood')
                    option(value="0") -- Seleccione usuario --
                    option(value="1") 1020433143
                    option(value="2") 1026138136
                    option(value="3") 1037618420
                    option(value="4") 1128430921
                    option(value="5") 1152683886
                    option(value="6") 15255651
                    option(value="7") 43222012
                    option(value="8") 71268442
                    option(value="9") 71703960
                    option(value="10") 8463111
                    option(value="11") 98514535
                    option(value="12") 98643619
                    option(value="13") Admin
                td
                  input(type="checkbox" id='hola' class='case' name='case')
```

Comment: Sería bueno que muestres tu HTML también, `#id_articulo` es para uno específico? Tal vez deberías usar clases en vez de un ID para eso.

Comment: Ya lo puse, por ejemplo solo me sirve si voy en orden, por el ejemplo escojo el segundo item de la tabla, me trae es el primer id_articulo,  necesito es que me traiga el id_articulo el cual este checkeado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo debes de agregar una validación a tu check

```
$(function() {
    //function ajax
    $('#example-table .processPreset').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elemento = $(this);
        var idArt = "";
        if( elemento.parent().parent().find(#idDeTuCheckbox).Ischecked())
        {
            idArt = elemento.parent().parent().find('#id_articulo').text();   
        }

        console.log(idArt);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/processPreset',
            method: 'post',
            data: { idArticulo: idArt },
            success: function(res) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Y este valida en el controlador si va vacio para no considerarlo para guardar.

Comment: Pero solo me sirve si voy en orden, por el ejemplo escojo el segundo item de la tabla, me trae es el primer `id_articulo`

Comment: El error esta por que toma `var elemento = $(this);` del boton y no del checkbox, alguna forma de solucionarlo.

Comment: es que debes de reccorrer la tabla para leer todos los registros checked, de ahí guardar en un arreglo los ids, y enviarlos para guardar. o en cuanto localiza el checked, haga el guardado individualmente. Me inclino más por la primer opción.